# Benefit of data locality

Tags: hosting, localization

What are the benefits of having a server in a country X for users in X to download data from rather than having the users in X download from a server in country Y?

Can you please provide sources of your information? Academic publications preferred.

**Update:** I don't need anyone to do my homework for me, I just don't know what to look for or what search keywords to use, so just giving me references to the papers would be enough. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think we're going to do your research/homework for you.

Comment: @lain I don't need you to do my homework, sorry. Please see the updated question. Please provide any references to papers, I'm having a hard time finding the papers.

Comment: Well, that's not what we're here for, and I'm not sure you're going to find a proper paper on the benefits of data locality any more than you'll find a proper paper on the dangers of lighting your face on fire - papers are generally not written on elementary/self-evident topics.  (Though you *might* have an easier time looking for case studies of businesses that aggressively pursued data locality - probably a mention or two of the benefits of geographic proximity to your servers in those.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the laws of physics more than a question about system administration.

Comment: Just going through my profile after a couple of years and remembering my uninformed self asking a question because I know nothing about the topic and wasn't getting help from Googling. What arrogance in the comments section here. This is so sad, why'd you people even bother to comment? You didn't help in any way. I'm sure it took @Andrew less time to point me to a paper than for you gents to write your useless comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The term is Content {Distribution,Delivery} Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). Here's a reference:

> Erik Nygren, Ramesh K. Sitaraman, and Jennifer Sun. ["The Akamai Network: A Platform for High-Performance Internet Applications, ACM SIGOPS Operating Systems Review, vol. 44, no. 3, July 2010."](http://www.akamai.com/dl/technical_publications/network_overview_osr.pdf)